# Limiting memory that raster package uses in R?

Tags: raster, r, memory

What's the easiest way to limit the memory the `raster` package uses in `R` to 5GB of RAM?

Ideally I want any raster that exceeds this size to be written to the hard drive and analysed from a temporary file.

I'm using Windows 7 (64Bit) and R version 3.0.3.

Here's some code I've been playing with on a machine with 16GB of RAM but it keeps maxing out as i'm dealing with large rasters:

```
require(raster)

memory.limit(size = 5000)
rasterOptions(format="GTiff",overwrite=TRUE,datatype="INT1S",
              tmpdir="C:/Research/BIN",tmptime=1.1,progress="text",chunksize=1000,
              maxmemory=1000)
rasterTmpFile("delete_me_")

r <- raster("myraster.tif")
r[r==0] <- NA
```

It is at this stage in the script that the RAM usage increases to take all 16GB and then stops working and cancels the function.

What do I need to change here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to read the rasters in in chunks instead of all at once. See the documentation for the [raster package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html), in particular - [Writing functions for large raster files](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/functions.pdf).